# Blackberry - ButtonField Controls Paint method

Tags: blackberry

I am extending the ButtonField and overriding the paint method to show the buttons in a differnet color. But its painting the whole button width. Part of the button stil shows as Gray when there is no focus and blue when its on focus. Can you please help me to resolve this issue?

thanks,
ramesh

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to override `protected void applyTheme()` to disable the extra painting that is going on.

Comment: +1. I did not know there is such a method. I looked in API 6.0 and neither `Field` nor `ButtonField` API has it, however I do see blog posts about this method usage.